# jquery dynamic subselection combining last and form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, selector

### Update

Tidied up the solution in progress and added some extra details

I have a form area which creates clones based on a template. In order to make sure the form transmits in an order, the script goes through the form at send time appending a number which defines the current batch set. Below is an over simplified representation of what is going on:

```
<form>
    <div class="batch-template">
        <div class="batch-piece">
            <a class="clone" />
            <input name="test-input">
            <input name="another-test-input">
            <select name="a-drop-down">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="batch-paste-area">
    </div>
</form>
```

When the page starts:

- The contents of "batch-template" are stored to an object variable
- The original template is removed from the page
- An instance of the template is appended to the "batch-paste-area"

The following is an example of the output created after clicking twice.

```
<form>
    <div class="batch-template">
    </div>
    <div class="batch-paste-area">
        <div class="batch-piece">
            <a class="clone" />
            <input name="test-input">
            <input name="another-test-input">
            <select name="a-drop-down">
        </div>
        <div class="batch-piece">
            <a class="clone" />
            <input name="test-input">
            <input name="another-test-input">
            <select name="a-drop-down">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When it comes to submitting the form: prior to serialization, I would like the script to loop through each "batch-piece" within "batch-paste-area" and add a count value to the end of each form field name. Continuing with the set above, the result (to a browser) would seem like that shown below:

```
<form>
    <div class="batch-template">
    </div>
    <div class="batch-paste-area">
        <div class="batch-piece">
            <a class="clone" />
            <input name="test-input1">
            <input name="another-test-input1">
            <select name="a-drop-down1">
        </div>
        <div class="batch-piece">
            <a class="clone" />
            <input name="test-input2">
            <input name="another-test-input2">
            <select name="a-drop-down2">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

So far, I can either loop through EVERY input within the paste area or just select the last.

Selecting the last batch-piece is simple:

```
var intCount = 1;
$('.batch-paste-area .batch-piece').each(function(){
    /* 
    * Would like to be able to loop through form fields here 
    * Below is an attempt to select all form fields for current set 
    */
    $(this + ' input, '+ this + ' select').each(function() {
        var strName = $(this).attr('name') + intCount;
        $(this).attr('name', strName);
    });
    intCount++;    
});
```

Comment: I advise you to not use the same value for multiple id attribute...

I don't really get your problem, we don't know what is "#batch-area-" + params.strBatchFocus.
I often work with model duplication in jQuery and I know there is some difficulties (as duplication of widgets and events) but i don't understand what you mean here.

Answer (score 0):

Frustratingly, I had actually tried the correct solution in advance but had forgotten to use the comma at the time!

```
var intCount = 1;
$('.batch-paste-area .batch-piece').each(function(){
    /* 
    * Would like to be able to loop through form fields here 
    * Below is an attempt to select all form fields for current set 
    */
    $(this).find("input, select").each(function() {
        var strName = $(this).attr('name') + intCount;
        $(this).attr('name', strName);
    });
    intCount++;    
});
```